# socket.gaierror while connecting to remote server

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, proxy

I am trying to connect to a remote database as follows:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ssh_address=('10.160.1.24', 22),
    ssh_username='Administrator',
    ssh_password=ssh_password,
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 5432)) as server:
    print("test")
```

But I am encountering this error:

```
remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 5432)) as server:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 879, in __init__
    self._local_interfaces = self._get_local_interfaces()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1378, in _get_local_interfaces
    local_if = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[-1]
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to me either. Errno 8 is `ENOEXEC`. There's no obvious reason why `gethostbyname_ex` or `gethostname` would fail with that errno. What OS?  If it were linux, I'd do an `strace <your program>` and try to determine what system call is actually generating that errno.

Comment: I am using a mac. Unfortunately, I am not aware of a strace replica in mac.

Comment: I don't do a lot of programming on mac, but it looks like `dtruss` is an equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of the lack of the local_bind_address parameter. The method seems to expect this parameter even though it is optional.